# оптимизация mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, php7

как можно оптимизировать скорость выполнения скрипта?
есть таблица ресурсов `modx_site_content` и таблица товаров `modx_ms2_products`

```
$id_p = '';
foreach ($_POST['parent'] as $key=>$value){
    $id_p.=$value.',';
}
$id_p = substr($id_p,0,-1);
    $sql = "SELECT `modx_site_content`.id,".$select." FROM `modx_site_content` 
        left join `modx_ms2_products` on `modx_ms2_products`.id = `modx_site_content`.id
        where `modx_site_content`.parent in (".$id_p.") and `modx_site_content`.`template` = 31 and `context_key`='web' AND ".$where."";
    $statement = $modx->query($sql);
    $parent = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $cost = 0;
        echo $sql;
        foreach ($parent as $result) {
                $j++;
                if ($vendor == 1){
                    $sqlVendor = "SELECT `modx_ms2_vendors`.name FROM `modx_ms2_products` 
                        left join `modx_ms2_vendors` on `modx_ms2_vendors`.id = `modx_ms2_products`.`vendor`
                        where `modx_ms2_products`.id = ".$result['id']." LIMIT 1";
                     //echo $sqlVendor;
                    $statementv = $modx->query($sqlVendor);
                    $parentv = $statementv->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $parentv[0]['name']);
                }
                if ($composition == 1){
                    $sqlComposition = "SELECT * FROM `modx_ms2_product_options` 
                        where product_id = ".$result['id']." LIMIT 1";
                    //echo $sqlComposition;
                    $statementc = $modx->query($sqlComposition);
                    $parentc = $statementc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($parentc as $res) {
                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $res['value']);
                    }
                }
                if ($size == 1){
                    $sizeStr = '';
                    foreach(json_decode($result['size']) as $item) {
                      $sizeStr.=$item.$_POST['delimeter'];
                    }
                    $sizeStr = substr($sizeStr,0,-1);
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                    ->setCellValue('J'.$i, $sizeStr);
                }
                if ($color == 1){
                    $colorStr = '';
                    $sqlColor = "SELECT * FROM `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` WHERE `tmplvarid`=2 and `contentid`=".$result['id']." limit 1";
                    $statementc = $modx->query($sqlColor);
                    $parentc = $statementc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    foreach ($parentc as $res) {
                        $nojson = json_decode($res['value'], true);
                        foreach($nojson as $row){
                            $colorStr.=$row['colorname'].';'.$row['color'].$_POST['delimeter'];
                        }
                        $colorStr = substr($colorStr,0,-1);

                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $colorStr);
                    }
                }
                if ($_POST['images']){
                    $gallery = '';
                    $sqlPath = "SELECT * FROM `modx_ms2_product_files` WHERE `product_id`=".$result['id']." limit 1";
                    $statementc = $modx->query($sqlPath);
                    $parentc = $statementc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $files[] += $result['id'];
                    foreach ($parentc as $res) {
                        $filelist = array();
                        if($handle = opendir('images/products/'.$res['path'].'thumb/')){
                            while($entry = readdir($handle)){
                                if ($entry) $gallery.='https://kristroom.ru/assets/images/products/'.$res['path'].$entry.$_POST['delimeter'];
                            }

                            closedir($handle);
                        }
                        $gallery = substr($gallery,0,-1);

                        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValue('I'.$i, $gallery);
                        $gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/products/'.$res['path'].$res['file']);
                        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
                        $objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
                        $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
                        $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
                        $objDrawing->setWidth(50);
                        $objDrawing->setHeight(50);
                        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('H'.$i);
                        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
                    }
                }
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $result['pagetitle'])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $result['article'])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, $result['alias'])
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $result['content'])
                ->setCellValue('K'.$i, $result['price']);
                $i++;
        }
```

Comment: Запросы к БД в циклах - это зло.

Comment: по другому не могу придумать так $_POST['parent'] содержит массив id

Comment: можно собрать все id в  цикле и выполнить все одним запросом вне цикла

Comment: это как? я не видел такой способ

Comment: @extrememod вы файл эксель парсите? Соберите все нужные данные из него, а потом делайте запросы

Comment: @extrememod собираете по частям запрос и в конце соединяете его. вот где у вас каждый раз встречается `...where xx = ".$var['i']"...` вы вместо того что прогонять запрос циклом и подставлять в запрос переменную - сделайте массив с нужнымы данным и потом в запросе через `foreach` перебераете массив и добавляете его в запрос как-то так: `$pre = ' AND '; $q_where .= $pre . ' xx = ".$item." ' ` и где "сборка" просто добавляете строку `$q_where` с уже сформированным кодом, аля `$query = $select.$join.$where.$q_where.$order.$limit`.

Comment: Если же с id  работа, то их можно не через = поставлять а как-то так: `where `modx_ms2_products`.id IN (". $array_of_ids .")`

Comment: добавил в вопрос изменения, но все ровно идет огромная нагрузка на сервер